# Unable to login to JHipster app deployed in Tomcat 6

Tags: jhipster

Deployed the JHipster generated app in Tomcat 6
Unable to login to the application using default login credentials(admin/admin)

running java 1.8

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? Check the browser console log, my suspicion is that you don't have a database configured or its failing to authenticate and your browser debugger will give some insight

Comment: Yes, following error is found when I load the app Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: and while I try to login, POST http://localhost:8081/hipster-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/authentication?cacheBuster=1480401963698 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Check you tomcat logs for any startup issues. If I recall, Jhipster is a self contained jar file built on spring boot so you should be able to run it via `java -jar "jarfile"`

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                                                               http://localhost:8081/hipster-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/authentication?cacheBuster=1480402811105 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: if you run it self contained, as ioneyed mentioned, the correct url is localhost:8081/api, not localhost:8081/hipster-app.../api...

Comment: It really depends on your version number, specific configuration (did you even configure your database?), etc. By default JHipster comes with its own embedded app server, so if you modify this, and if you use a very old version of Tomcat, you need to tell exactly what you are doing if you want us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a more recent version of Tomcat. Spring Boot does not support Tomcat 6 (Servlet 2.5), it requires Servlet 3 which can be found in Tomcat 7+ ([Tomcat and Servlet versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)). If you need to use an older version of Tomcat, you can try to implement https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-legacy